# How do I run nohup as a different user without spawning two processes?

Tags: bash, process, nohup

I'm trying to nohup a command and run it as a different user, but every time I do this two processes are spawned.

For example:

```
$ nohup su -s /bin/bash nobody -c "my_command" > outfile.txt &
```

This definitely runs my_command as nobody, but there's an extra process that I don't want to shown up:

```
$ ps -Af
.
.
.
root ... su -s /bin/bash nobody my_command
nobody ... my_command
```

And if I kill the root process, the nobody process still lives... but is there a way to not run the root process at all? Since getting the id of my_command and killing it is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 14):

This could be achieved as:

```
su nobody -c "nohup my_command >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

and to write the pid of 'my_command' in a pidFile:

```
pidFile=/var/run/myAppName.pid
touch $pidFile
chown nobody:nobody $pidFile
su nobody -c "nohup my_command >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo \$! > '$pidFile'"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
nohup runuser nobody -c "my_command my_command_args....." < /dev/null >> /tmp/mylogfile 2>&1 &
```

Comment: what's the `runuser` bit?

Comment: do a `man runuser`.  its not an argument of nohup but its own separate command a lot like su

Answer (score 2):

If the user with nologin shell, run as follows:

```
su - nobody -s /bin/sh -c "nohup your_command parameter  >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Or:

```
runuser - nobody -s /bin/sh -c "nohup your_command parameter  >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Or:

```
sudo su - nobody -s /bin/sh -c "nohup your_command parameter  >/dev/null 2>&1 &"

sudo runuser -u nobody -s /bin/sh -c "nohup your_command parameter  >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

Answer (score 1):

You might do best to create a small script in e.g. `/usr/local/bin/start_my_command` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup my_command > outfile.txt &
```

Use `chown` and `chmod` to set it to be executable and owned by `nobody`, then just run `su nobody -c /usr/local/bin/start_my_command`.

Answer (score 0):

A note on running this on a session, is that if you run in background, there is a job associated with the session, and background jobs may be killed (the su -c gets around this).

To disassociate the process from the shell (so you can exit the shell but keep the process running), use `disown`.