# How to get the process ID to kill a nohup process?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, nohup

I'm running a nohup process on the server. When I try to kill it my putty console closes instead.

this is how I try to find the process ID:

```
ps -ef |grep nohup
```

this is the command to kill

```
 kill -9 1787 787
```

Comment: As an aside, [don't indiscriminately use `kill -9`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill)

Answer (score 520, accepted):

When using `nohup` and you put the task in the background, the background operator (`&`) will give you the PID at the command prompt. If your plan is to manually manage the process, you can save that PID and use it later to kill the process if needed, via `kill PID` or `kill -9 PID` (if you need to force kill). Alternatively, you can find the PID later on by `ps -ef | grep "command name"` and locate the PID from there. Note that `nohup` keyword/command itself does not appear in the `ps` output for the command in question.

If you use a script, you could do something like this in the script:

```
nohup my_command > my.log 2>&1 &
echo $! > save_pid.txt
```

This will run `my_command` saving all output into `my.log` (in a script, `$!` represents the PID of the last process executed). The `2` is the file descriptor for standard error (`stderr`) and `2>&1` tells the shell to route standard error output to the standard output (file descriptor `1`). It requires `&1` so that the shell knows it's a file descriptor in that context instead of just a file named `1`. The `2>&1` is needed to capture any error messages that normally are written to standard error into our `my.log` file (which is coming from standard output). See [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) for more details on handling I/O redirection with the shell.

If the command sends output on a regular basis, you can check the output occasionally with `tail my.log`, or if you want to follow it "live" you can use `tail -f my.log`. Finally, if you need to kill the process, you can do it via:

```
kill -9 `cat save_pid.txt`
rm save_pid.txt
```

Comment: A slight clarification, it's not `nohup` per se, that prints the PID, it's the final `&` which backgrounds it, e.g. `ls &` would show the PID for running `ls`

Comment: @karmakaze yes, indeed, thanks for making that clear!

Comment: What does the '2>&1' do ?

Comment: @Viraj `2` is the "standard error" file descriptor. `>` is the shell redirection, and `&1` is the "standard output" file descriptor (the `&` is needed here so the shell won't think I am referring to a file named `1`). So `2 > &1` redirects any standard error output to the standard input. Since the prior `> my.log` means to redirect standard output to `my.log`, we need a way to ensure that error messages also go to `my.log`. `2 > &1` ensures that such errors go to standard output, which in turn goes to `my.log`. See [I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: `echo $!` gives me the pid of nohup instead of the process spawned: https://paste.fedoraproject.org/428697/99695314/

Comment: @NehalJWani when you run `nohup ...` at the command line, it gives you the process Id of the command (in this case, `python3`) you are running. The `nohup` itself isn't running with its own process Id. In your example, if you were to `kill -9 24246`, your `python3` process would be killed. To have a more complete example in your case, try `ps ax | grep 24246` and see what's there.

Comment: This is misleading - while `nohup` does not appear in the process list, the command it runs does.

Comment: @lorenzog the fact that `nohup` does not appear in the process list is simply the way it works. I don't see how this makes my original answer "misleading" and worthy of down-vote.

Comment: @lurker it reads like "the entire nohup command does not appear in the process list" which is confusing

Comment: @lorenzog a downvote means "this answer is not useful". Although it's a valid comment, I think it's a bit of a stretch to say that this very minor point of confusion (which is cleared up by common understanding of how ps works) makes the answer not useful. I just updated the wording to help clarify, however, to avoid the potential ambiguity.

Comment: I have this wrapped in sh -c ''. How can I put this inside, ie. in one line?

Comment: @Mvorisek `&` acts as a command delimiter so you could try, `sh -c "nohup my_command > my.log 2>&1 & echo $! > save_pid.txt"`. It might work, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: I tried "kill -9 `cat save_pid.txt`" but got an error (bash: kill: cat: arguments must be process or job IDs). Instead "kill -9 $(cat save_pid.txt)" worked fine.

Comment: @GDN based upon the error looks like you didn't use proper back ticks. `$(...)` is a better method anyway.

Comment: Is there any reason that your ```ps -ef  | grep "command_name"``` would not work? I was trying the same and I can't find the process with the name.

Comment: @rsmith54 it depends upon what the command is that you ran. If it's a script based command, what `ps` shows might be a subprocess or multiple subprocess names. So it's not always effective.

Comment: @mvorisek @lurker `$!` should be escaped, `bash -c "nohup my_command > my.log 2>&1 & echo \$! > save_pid.txt"`, thanks to @javdev, refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/30614195/2227031

Comment: @jk2K indeed, thank you for pointing it out! That's important if using the `bash -c "..."` form.

Comment: @lurker This works really well thank you a bunch for your answer.  I've been trying to run this in a bash script and it always write an empty value to the .txt file, but when I write it directly to the terminal everything works fine.  Any ideas what I could do to make the .sh script work?

Comment: @skrhee If I'm reading your comment correctly, read up on the differences between single and double quotes.

Answer (score 148):

I am using red hat linux on a VPS server (and via SSH - putty), for me the following worked:

First, you list all the running processes:

```
ps -ef
```

Then in the first column you find your user name; I found it the following three times:

- One was the SSH connection
- The second was an FTP connection
- The last one was the nohup process

Then in the second column you can find the PID of the nohup process and you only type:

```
kill PID
```

(replacing the PID with the nohup process's PID of course)

And that is it!

I hope this answer will be useful for someone I'm also very new to bash and SSH, but found 95% of the knowledge I need here :)

Comment: I think you meant PID instead of UID here?

Comment: I agree with @wprins. Killing the UID didn't work for me, but killing the PID did.

Comment: In my case I  ran a test shell script(long_running_script.sh) with nohup and & and dint know how to stop it. Finally, I did a ps -ef | grep long_running* and fouund the PID. Then did a kill PID

Comment: (Tangentially, `grep long_running*` is effectively identical to `grep long_runnin`, except if you run it in a directory where you have files which match the wildcard. If there is more than one match, this will do entirely the wrong thing. Generally, quote your regular expressions, and learn the differences between regular expressions and shell wildcards.)

Answer (score 87):

suppose i am running ruby script in the background with below command

```
nohup ruby script.rb &
```

then i can get the pid of above background process by specifying command name. In my case command is ruby.

```
ps -ef | grep ruby
```

output

```
ubuntu   25938 25742  0 05:16 pts/0    00:00:00 ruby test.rb
```

Now you can easily kill the process by using kill command

```
kill 25938
```

Comment: Sanjay, just so I'm sure I'm not missing anything, what part of your answer is new or different from the answers provided years ago? `ps -ef` and `kill` were both well covered above, so what is the new part?

Comment: ps -ef will give you the long list of output and searching from this long list will be difficult. so i think ps -ef | grep ruby is better command to search pid than just doing ps -ef

Comment: This answer helped me perfectly, Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

**jobs -l** should give you the pid for the list of nohup processes.
kill (-9) them gently.
;)

Comment: Only if the job was started in the current shell.  And don't `kill -9` unless you know that regular signals do not work.

Comment: This is useful, if you're on some docker image where ps isn't installed :-)

Answer (score 14):

Suppose you are executing a java program with nohup you can get java process id by

```
ps aux | grep java
```

output

```
xxxxx     9643  0.0  0.0  14232   968 pts/2
```

then you can kill the process by typing

```
sudo kill 9643
```

or lets say that you need to kill all the java processes then just use

```
sudo killall java
```

this command kills all the java processes. you can use this with process. just give the process name at the end of the command

```
sudo killall {processName}
```

Answer (score 13):

You could try

```
kill -9 `pgrep [command name]`
```

Comment: very nice! I used `pkill [command name]` you can use the `-o` flag for killing the oldest matching process, or `-n` to use the newest one instead.

Answer (score 8):

If your application always uses the same port, you can kill all the processes in that port like this.

`kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:8080)`

Answer (score 5):

This works in `Ubuntu`

Type this to find out the `PID`

```
ps aux | grep java
```

All the running process regarding to java will be shown

In my case is

```
johnjoe      3315  9.1  4.0 1465240 335728 ?      Sl   09:42   3:19 java -jar batch.jar
```

Now kill it `kill -9 3315`

The zombie process finally stopped.

Answer (score 4):

when you create a job in nohup it will tell you the process ID !

```
nohup sh test.sh &
```

the output will show you the process ID like

```
25013
```

you can kill it then :

```
kill 25013
```

Comment: This merely repeats information from the accepted answer from 2013. As pointed out there, the background operator `&`, not `nohup`, is what causes the PID to be printed by the shell.

Answer (score 3):

I started django server with the following command.

```
nohup manage.py runserver <localhost:port>
```

This works on CentOS:

```
:~ ns$netstat -ntlp
:~ ns$kill -9 PID
```

Comment: This is the go to for solving the `process not found` confusion with nohup.

Comment: You might need to add sudo to that command if you don't see the PID

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -ef | grep <file_type>| grep <username>
```

For example, if you are running a Python file, use the following command:

```
ps -ef | grep python | grep user_name
```

It will list all the python processes that are initiated by you. Now you can kill those processes as:

```
kill -9 <p_id>
```

Answer (score 1):

I often do this way. Try this way :

```
ps aux | grep script_Name
```

Here, *script_Name* could be any script/file run by **nohup**.
This command gets you a **process ID**. Then use this **command below to kill** the script running on nohup.

```
kill -9 1787 787
```

Here, 1787 and 787 are Process ID as mentioned in the question as an example.
This should do what was intended in the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unaware of the PID, then first find it using TOP command

**top -U userid**

```
PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
```

You will get the PID using top, then perform the kill operation.

```sh
$ kill -9 <PID>
```

Answer (score 0):

Today I met the same problem. And since it was a long time ago, I totally forgot which command I used and when. I tried three methods:

1. Using the STIME shown in `ps -ef` command. This shows the time you start your process, and it's very likely that you nohup you command just before you close ssh(depends on you) . Unfortunately I don't think the latest command is the command I run using nohup, so this doesn't work for me.
2. Second is the PPID, also shown in `ps -ef` command. It means Parent Process ID, the ID of process that creates the process. The ppid is 1 in ubuntu for process that using nohup to run. Then you can use `ps --ppid "1"` to get the list, and check TIME(the total CPU time your process use) or CMD to find the process's PID.
3. Use `lsof -i:port` if the process occupy some ports, and you will get the command. Then just like the answer above, use `ps -ef | grep command` and you will get the PID.

Once you find the PID of the process, then can use `kill pid` to terminal the process.

Answer (score 0):

This works for mi fine on mac

```
kill -9 `ps -ef | awk '/nohup/{ print \$2 }'`
```

Answer (score 0):

About losing your `putty`: often the `ps ... | awk/grep/perl/...` process gets matched, too!  So the old school trick is like this

```
ps -ef | grep -i [n]ohup
```

That way the regex search doesn't match the regex search process!

Comment: The general idea is correct, but `nohup` will usually not show up in a `ps` listing because it's a shell builtin.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on a remote server, check memory usage with `top` , and find your process and its ID. After that, just execute `kill [your process ID]` .