# Unable to kill nohup process

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh, kill-process

If I start the script by `./test.sh &`, I am able to kill using  `kill -SIGINT PID`.

But if I start my shell script using `nohup ./test.sh &` I am unable to kill the process using `kill -SIGINT PID`.

Kindly need your advice to kill the script using `kill -SIGINT PID`

Comment: See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SIGINT signal means *interrupt from keyboard*; that's why it terminates a script run in foreground, but not in background neither using `nohup`.

To properly terminate your process use `kill -TERM PID`, which works in the 3 cases.

Comment: what is the difference between -SIGNTERM and -TERM?