# How to keep Laravel Queue system running on server

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-artisan

I recently setup a Laravel Queue system. The basics are a cronjob calls a command which adds jobs to a queue and calls a second command which sends an email.

The system works when I ssh into my server and run php artisan queue:listen, but if I close my terminal the listener shuts down and the jobs stack up  and sit in queue until I ssh back in and run listen again.

What is the best way to keep my queue system running in the background without needing to keep my connection open via ssh?

I tried running `php artisan queue:work --daemon`, and it completed the jobs in the queue, but when I closed my terminal it closed the connection and the background process.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Running

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &
```

Will prevent the command exiting when you log out.

The trailing ampersand (&) causes process start in the background, so you can continue to use the shell and do not have to wait until the script is finished.

See [nohup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

This will output information to a file entitled nohup.out in the directory where you run the command. If you have no interest in the output, you can redirect stdout and stderr to /dev/null; similarly, you could output it into your normal Laravel log. For example

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon > /dev/null 2>&1 &

nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon >> storage/logs/laravel.log &
```

But you should also use something like [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) to ensure that the service remains running and is restarted after crashes/failures.

Use >> to *append* to laravel.log. Using a single > will replace the file each time.

Comment: First I needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29292637/470749 Then `nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon > storage/logs/laravel.log &` worked for me. Note: if you want to kill the nohup daemon, you need to first discover its PID by running something like `ps -ef |grep artisan`. Then you can run `kill [pid]` http://stackoverflow.com/q/17385794/470749

Comment: This is a poor solution because once you issue a queue:reset the worker dies and you don't have a restart mechanism, just use supervisord, spawn 2 workers and you will be good as gold when you have high volumes. As a side note, you will need to respawn new workers each time you make a code change.

Comment: @z900collector The answer explicitly says you should use something like Supervisord and always has done.

Comment: @BenSwinburne, have you heard of Linux screen? What about fg and bg?

Comment: If you're using laravel forge - be sure to run:  `sudo su - forge` so that your command is ran as the forge user

Answer (score 63):

You should use linux [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/index.html)

Installation is simple and on Ubuntu I can install it with following command:

```
apt-get install supervisor
```

Supervisor configuration files are located in /etc/supervisor/conf.d directory.

```
[program:email-queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/laravel-example/artisan queue:work redis --queue=emailqueue --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=forge
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/laravel-example//storage/logs/supervisord.log
```

For each process you should create a new process configuration file. With this configuration, listener will retry each job 3 times. Also Supervisor will restart listener if it fails or if system restarts.

Comment: more instruction is here, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-manage-supervisor-on-ubuntu-and-debian-vps

Comment: Worth noting this answer is also the Laravel documented way of doing things: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#supervisor-configuration

Answer (score 22):

The command

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &
```

was correct, it would allow the process to continue after closing the SSH connection; however, this is only a short term fix. Once your server is rebooted or any issue causes the process to stop you will need to go back and run the command again. When that occurs, you never know. It could happen on a Friday night, so it is better to implement a long term solution.

I ended up switching over to Supervisord, this can be installed on Ubuntu as easy as

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

For AWS-AMI or RedHat users you can follow the set of instructions I outlined in this question:

[Setting up Supervisord on a AWS AMI Linux Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28702780/setting-up-supervisord-on-a-aws-ami-linux-server)

Comment: Hello, can you help with my problem? I'm using supervisord and the job was executed, but cant create a file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47715537/laravel-supervisord-cannot-create-file

Comment: So why did you not accept the answer that suggested supervisor?

Comment: That answer only applies to Ubuntu users, my answer links to a separate question with how to set it up on RedHat based distros. Also, I answered Dev 15 2016, that other answer which is specific to only Ubuntu users came in June 2017.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but @deewwald was probably referring to [the answer here you said you would likely accept](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625847/6089612) - AFAICT it was the first (meaningful) answer posted, it suggested Supervisor, and it is not specific to any OS.

Comment: Ahh I agree that answer was meaningful, and answered the question, however it really is a bad solution. In order to have a queue process reliably some sort or process monitor should be integrated. The laravel community seems to lean towards Supervisor, however I have seen Monit used with success as well.

Comment: Sticking with my pedantry, *it really is a bad solution* - AFAICT it is 100% correct.  It is also practically identical to your own answer, which you accepted.  It answers the original question, and goes on to suggest the better approach (Supervisor) - exactly as yours does.  The biggest difference is the other question was posted 2 months earlier.  As both you yourself and dewwwald said, it seems like it should be the accepted answer.  Anyway, sorry for quibbling, they're both correct, and they helped me yesterday.

Comment: I selected it as the correct answer are you happy now?

Comment: Using supervisor is the the correct way.

Answer (score 21):

**Note:**
Laravel 10 now has **'process' interaction**
This should be used to overcome when your host blocks the `pid` lookup such as siteground

see: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/releases#process

---

From https://gist.github.com/ivanvermeyen/b72061c5d70c61e86875

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class EnsureQueueListenerIsRunning extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'queue:checkup';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Ensure that the queue listener is running.';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        if ( ! $this->isQueueListenerRunning()) {
            $this->comment('Queue listener is being started.');
            $pid = $this->startQueueListener();
            $this->saveQueueListenerPID($pid);
        }

        $this->comment('Queue listener is running.');
    }

    /**
     * Check if the queue listener is running.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isQueueListenerRunning()
    {
        if ( ! $pid = $this->getLastQueueListenerPID()) {
            return false;
        }

        $process = exec("ps -p $pid -opid=,cmd=");
        //$processIsQueueListener = str_contains($process, 'queue:listen'); // 5.1
        $processIsQueueListener = ! empty($process); // 5.6 - see comments

        return $processIsQueueListener;
    }

    /**
     * Get any existing queue listener PID.
     *
     * @return bool|string
     */
    private function getLastQueueListenerPID()
    {
        if ( ! file_exists(__DIR__ . '/queue.pid')) {
            return false;
        }

        return file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/queue.pid');
    }

    /**
     * Save the queue listener PID to a file.
     *
     * @param $pid
     *
     * @return void
     */
    private function saveQueueListenerPID($pid)
    {
        file_put_contents(__DIR__ . '/queue.pid', $pid);
    }

    /**
     * Start the queue listener.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    private function startQueueListener()
    {
        //$command = 'php-cli ' . base_path() . '/artisan queue:listen --timeout=60 --sleep=5 --tries=3 > /dev/null & echo $!'; // 5.1
        //$command = 'php-cli ' . base_path() . '/artisan queue:work --timeout=60 --sleep=5 --tries=3 > /dev/null & echo $!'; // 5.6 - see comments

 //handle memory issues
 $command = env('PATH_PHP') . ' ' . base_path() . '/artisan queue:work --queue=default --delay=0 --memory=256 --once --timeout=60 --sleep=5 --tries=3 > /dev/null & echo $!';

        $pid = exec($command);

        return $pid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, that is a unique way to ensure a queue is running! Nice because requires installing no new dependencies, just need a handle on CRONTAB. Any permissions settings gotchas?

Comment: No permission issues. Just need to be careful with php versions and paths, sometimes they are different from shell. alse exec() is often turned off on shared hosting..

Comment: Updated for 5.6 see comments on the link for 5.1

Comment: this use `queue:work` which means didn't listen any code changes, or at least need manually restart the process. but in the code i didnt see any restarting.. any idea?

Comment: @davidvalentino you need to add to the kernel    $schedule->command('queue:checkup')->everyFiveMinutes();

Comment: @HarryBosh yes that to ensure to queue is running every 5 minutes, so if the old queue:work is active, it will never detect any code changes,, unless the pid is killed

Comment: This has really saved my website! The supervisor which others were recommending was not available to me, and this method works very well. No issue. I did have to change the command slightly for my environment.

Answer (score 21):

1)`sudo apt install supervisor`  or

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

2)`cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d`
3)create new file inside

```
sudo vim queue-worker.conf
```

File Content

```
[program:email-queue]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/laravelproject/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/laravelproject/storage/logs/supervisord.log
```

4)`sudo supervisorctl reread`

when run this command get output queue-worker:available

5)`sudo supervisorctl update`

when run this command get output queue-worker:added process group

other command

1)`sudo supervisorctl reload`

when run this command get output Restarted supervisord

2)`sudo service supervisor restart`

Comment: yes its work for me i also try another method i make a schedule which start my queue work artisan in every 5 minutes this is also work

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using this on?

Comment: working for me(server Ubuntu 20.04 / php 7.4, Laravel 8, radis ) . but i changed `user=root` to `user=www-data`  . comand line : `command=php /var/www/path-to-project/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3 --max-time=3600`

Answer (score 11):

> **Installing Supervisor**

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

> **Configuring Supervisor**

step 1 : goto **/etc/supervisor/conf.d** directory

```
cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d
```

step 2 : create a worker file **laravel-worker.conf** that will listen queue

```
sudo nano laravel-worker.conf
```

***Note :** Now assuming that your laravel app is inside `/var/www/html` directory

```
project folder is : /var/www/html/LaravelApp
```

step 3 : paste below code in **laravel-worker.conf** and save file

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/LaravelApp/artisan queue:listen redis --queue=default --sleep=3 --tries=3 
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile= /var/www/html/LaravelApp/storage/logs/worker.log
```

***Note :** Here is assumed that you are using **redis** for queue connection

in .env file `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis`

```
command=php /var/www/html/LaravelApp/artisan queue:listen redis
```

if you are using other connection then , general syntax will be :

```
command= php [project_folder_path]/artisan queue:listen [connection_name]
```

[connection_name] can be any of **sync** , **database** , **beanstalkd** , **sqs** , **redis**

step 4 : create a worker file **laravel-schedule.conf** that will run `artisan schedule:run` command at **every 1 minute (60 seconds)** (*you can change it as per your requirement)

```
[program:laravel-schedule]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/bin/bash -c 'while true; do date && php /var/www/html/LaravelApp/artisan schedule:run; sleep 60; done'
autostart=true
autorestart=true
numprocs=1
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

step 5 : Starting Supervisor : run below commands

```
sudo supervisorctl reread

sudo supervisorctl update

sudo supervisorctl start all
```

> ***Note :** Whenever you make changes in any of configuration **.conf** files , run above commands of **Step 5**

Extra usefull information :

- to stop all supervisorctl process :  `sudo supervisorctl stop all`
- to restart all supervisorctl process :  `sudo supervisorctl restart all`

usefull links :

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker

http://supervisord.org/index.html

Answer (score 10):

For systems with **systemd** as init service you could use the following service, adapting it to your project (create it on /etc/systemd/system/queue-handler.service):

```
[Unit]
Description = Queue Handler - Project
After = network-online.target, mysql.service

[Service]
User = www-data
Type = simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/project
ExecStart = /usr/bin/php /var/www/project/artisan queue:work --tries=3
Restart = on-failure
RestartSec=5s
RestartPreventExitStatus = 255

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
```

Reload the configurations and enable it on boot:

```sh
$ systemctl enable queue-handler.service
$ systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: This is probably the most elegant solution for most systems as it doesn't include any dependencies. systemd/`systemctl` is a very important utility that not a lot of people know about, though it is so much more important than pm2/supervisor.

Answer (score 8):

## Using pm2

I had JS script running with [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) (Advanced, production process manager for Node.js) Which was the only one I was running. But now as I got one more process to keep running.

I created `process.yml` to run both with a single command. 
Check the first one would run `php artisan queue: listen`

```
# process.yml at /var/www/ which is root dir of the project
apps:
  # Run php artisan queue:listen to execute queue job
  - script    : 'artisan'
    name      : 'artisan-queue-listen'
    cwd       : '/var/www/'
    args      : 'queue:listen' # or queue:work
    interpreter : 'php'

  # same way add any other script if any.
```

Now run:

```
> sudo pm2 start process.yml
```

[Check more options and feature of pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/)

Answer (score 7):

For those who are already running **NodeJS** on their production environments. I use PM2 to manage app processes.

```
# install
npm install -g pm2

# in project dir with your CI or dev setup tool 
# --name gives task a name so that you can later manage it
# -- delimits arguments that get passed to the script
pm2 start artisan --interpreter php --name queue-worker -- queue:work --daemon
```

I use Vagrant in development and setup NodeJS and this process using only inline vagrant scripts.

When you use PM2 in development you can use one of the many watchers to manage the restart. Simply run `pm2 restart queue-worker` when you pick up a change. In production I don't recommend this approach, rather opt for a build tool that can follow this process.

```
# 1. stop pm task to ensure that no unexpected behaviour occurs during build
pm2 stop queue-worker
# 2. do your build tasks
...
# 3. restart queue so that it loads the new code
pm2 restart queue-worker
```

Comment: Also, run pm2 startup just incase of server restart.

Answer (score 7):

The best way is PM2 (Advanced, production process manager for Node.js) that you can monit your queues and see their's logs.

with command below in your project directory, run queue worker :

```
pm2 start artisan --name laravel-worker --interpreter php -- queue:work --daemon
```

Answer (score 6):

There is more than one way to skin this cat depending on your environment, and its configuration capabilities. Some are on shared hosting, some have whm access...

A more direct and maintainable way is is the following;

In your kernal file add `$schedule->command('queue:work')->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();` to your schedule method.

This will run the queue work command every five minutes.

```
/**
 * Define the application's command schedule.
 *
 * @param Schedule $schedule
 * @return void
 */
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('queue:work')->everyFiveMinutes()->withoutOverlapping();
}
```

See the laravel documentation - https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#defining-schedules

Answer (score 5):

Since this was a Laravel-specific question, I thought I would suggest a Lravel-specific answer. Since you are already using cronjobs on this server, I would recommend that you set up the shell command as a recurring cronjob to always verify that the worker is running. You could either set up the shell command to run natively through cron on your server, or you could use the Laravel console kernel to manage the command and add logic, such as checking whether you already have a worker running and, if not, go ahead and start it back up.

Depending on how often you need to run your command, you could do this as infrequently as once a week, or even once a minute. This would give you the ability to make sure that your workers are continuously running, without having to add any overhead to your server, such as Supervisor. Giving permissions to a 3rd party package like supervisor is ok if you trust it, but if you can avoid needing to rely on it, you may want to consider this approach instead.

An example of using this to do what you want would be to have a cronjob that runs each hour. It would execute the following in sequential order from within a custom Laravel console command:

\Artisan::call('queue:restart');

\Artisan::call('queue:work --daemon');

Note that this applies for older versions of Laravel (up to 5.3) but I haven't tested on newer versions.

Comment: Although this is one option and would work, in the worst case this would result in an hour of downtime for the queued tasks. Also, this looks like it would create a new process each time the cron runs, if so eventually you would run out of memory.

Comment: An hour of downtime? I just meant that the two artisan commands should be run in sequential order within the cronjob, not an hour apart. I will update the original answer to reflect this. This would not cause a memory issue since the restart command kills the previous process.

Comment: Regarding potential hour of downtime, we had a problem on our server where the artisan daemon worker would end up killed off for unknown reasons and would not stay alive. Supervisor was the only way to ensure it was revived at death.

Comment: The above code should also work. You could call these commands as often as you want, as often as every minute. So I don't understand the comment about having an hour of downtime using this method. You have control over how often you check and restart the daemon. The whole point in posting this was just to give an example of how to do it using only Laravel. There are definitely other ways to do it. But this way does not rely on an external package to be installed.

Comment: Fair enough, you got my upvote. Interested to see if anyone has any comments on why not just do it this way vs using process monitor.

Comment: I think that most people don't mind installing a process monitor, but others might not want to give that level of access to an external package that they don't control. It's personal preference. The service monitor is probably cleaner if you don't mind doing that type of install on the server, but this method achieves the same without any additional external dependencies and should be platform agnostic. But both have plusses and minuses.

Comment: +1 This is the 'PHP way' to do it, efficient for shared hosting platforms where no custom programs (such as supervisor) are allowed to be installed.

Answer (score 2):

What if you start the listening within a screen? See here: http://aperiodic.net/screen/quick_reference
Then even if you log out, the screen would still be active and running. Not sure why the daemonization doesnt work though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) tool. it's very small and useful for any type of process management and monitoring.

After Downloading binary package from [this link](https://mmonit.com/monit/#download), you can extract it to a folder on your system and then copy two files from the package to your system to install it:

```
cd /path/to/monit/folder
cp ./bin/monit /usr/sbin/monit
cp ./conf/monitrc /etc/monitrc
```

Now edit `/etc/monitrc` base on your needs([reference doc](https://mmonit.com/monit/#slideshow)). then create a [init control file](https://mmonit.com/wiki/Monit/Upstart) to enable monit on startup. now start monit like this:

```
initctl reload-configuration
start monit
```

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS7

```
yum install supervisor
```

Then create a file in /etc/supervisord.d/filename.ini 
With content

```
[program:laravel-worker]
command=/usr/bin/php /home/appuser/public_html/artisan queue:listen
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
numprocs=5
priority=999
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=1
startretries=3
user=appuser
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/path/logpath/artisan.log
```

Then start the supervisord service using

```
systemctl restart supervisord
```

Enable supervisord service to run on boot using

```
systemctl enable supervisord
```

Check if the service is running using

```
ps aux | grep artisan
```

You should see the process running if it was set up properly. Similar to the output below.

```
[root@server ~]# ps aux | grep artisan
appuser 17444  0.1  0.8 378656 31068 ?        S    12:43   0:05 /usr/bin/php /home/appuser/public_html/artisan queue:listen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Docker containers.

checkout:

- [Docker + Laravel queue:work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884802/docker-laravel-queuework)
- https://laravel-news.com/laravel-scheduler-queue-docker

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the result without any service monitor or third party software. The solution is working fine but I am not sure if it is the best way.

**Solution**

Just run cli command in the following way in your function.

```
use Illuminate\Console\Command;

public function callQueue()
{
        $restart = 'php-cli ' . base_path() . '/artisan queue:restart > /dev/null & echo $!'; 
        $work = 'php-cli ' . base_path() . '/artisan queue:work --timeout=0 --sleep=5 --tries=3 > /dev/null & echo $!';
        exec($restart);
        exec($work);
}

$job = (new jobName())->delay(Carbon::now()->addSeconds(5));
dispatch($job);
```

**Reason**

The reason I have used these two commands is because the command associated with `$restart` prevent having any memory issue according to a comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51934647/10003098)
and the command associated with `$work` ensures that the command is successfully executed before the job.

Comment: This solution does not work for me. When you do `> /dev/null` on the `queue:work` the queue isn't executed at all. Doesn't matter if you call the function before or after the `dispatch(...)`. If I remove the `> /dev/null` then it works, but it has a big delay while trying to send the email.

Comment: This isn't valid PHP; visibility modifiers (`public`, `private`, etc.) on non-method functions are invalid syntax. Also, how is the `jobName` class defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can run command line:

```
php artisan queue:listen --queue=queue_name --tries=1 --memory=128 --timeout=300 >>  storage/logs/queue_log.log &
```

Check process running:

```
ps aux | grep php
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWS SQS Connection on Ubuntu

Installing Supervisor

```
sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

Configuring Supervisor

step 1 : goto /etc/supervisor/conf.d directory

```
cd /etc/supervisor/conf.d
```

step 2 : create a worker file laravel-worker.conf that will listen queue

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/website/queue:work sqs
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=root
numprocs=2
redirect_stderr=true
startsecs=0
stdout_logfile=/opt/bitnami/nginx/html/website/storage/logs/supervisord.log
```

4)`sudo supervisorctl reread`

when run this command get output queue-worker:available

5)`sudo supervisorctl update`

when run this command get output queue-worker:added process group

other command

1)`sudo supervisorctl reload`

when run this command get output Restarted supervisord

2)`sudo service supervisor restart`

3)`sudo supervisorctl status`

see the status of the process

Comment: There are already numerous answers explaining how to use `supervisord`. This answer doesn't appear to be adding anything to those.

Answer (score 0):

I executed with this command and my command was executed in the background and after that I took ‍`htop` and saw that my command was running and I trusted it, maybe it will help you.

In addition, if there is a problem, it will be recorded in the Laravel log.

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon >> storage/logs/laravel.log 2>&1 &
```

Comment: if the server reboots, you will need to run again, or if the process fails etc. this works short term but not the best for long term

Answer (score -2):

I simply used `php artisan queue:work --tries=3 &` which keeps the process running in the background.
But it sometimes stops.
I don't know why this is happening

### Edit

I solved this issue by using supervisor.
Put a supervisor script that runs this php script, and that will run every time the server runs

Comment: It stops because your server reboots sometimes.