# Laravel unable to modify queued job code

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, jobs, supervisord

When I send a job that fails due to an exception such as `'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: sender'` and I fix the code and re-fire the event, the previous code runs again and I get the same error.

I have no idea why Laravel re-runs my old code over and over. I'd obviously like to be able to fix the mistakes that are breaking my job execution.

I've tried both `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan queue:flush` and those have no effect. Any help?

Comment: Have you run `php artisan clear-compiled` ?

Comment: I think `php artisan clear-compiled` worked for me. Is there documentation on it. I understand it clears my compiled classes. And `composer dump-autoload` only clears the classes that were imported and not the classes I'm generating in my application code? Is that why dump-autoload isn't useful?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to run `php artisan clear-compiled` to clear compiled files.

If you look at `config/compile.php` you will see some extra providers (or other classes) are cached by default by Laravel.

If you made any changes for example in `EventServiceProvider` and it was earlier cached, Laravel won't see those changes in case `php artisan optimize` command was earlier launched (and looking at https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json you will see it is launched after running `composer install` or `composer update`).

This feature has nothing in common with composer itself but with Laravel that's why running `composer dump-autoload` won't help.

Comment: `composer update` seems to run `php artisan clear-compiled` and `composer dump-autoload` so that's an option as well.

Comment: @timpeterson That's true but you don't want to run always `composer update` because it will update all packages and on production you don't want it.

Comment: This didn't work for me, had to run `php artisan queue:restart` for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 8):

My Laravel 5.1 config/compile.php file is empty but this helped me:

sudo service beanstalkd restart

and

php artisan queue:restart

Laravel often lacks of good and accurate documentation.

Comment: I tried both answers but after restarting supervisor, the new jobs where taken.


`supervisorctl restart *`

Comment: Isnt it the goal to get the new jobs (corrected code) running?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, supervisor was the issue.

This is the only process that works consistently for me:

1. run 'service supervisor stop'
2. run 'service supervisor start'
3. quit your browser, restart it, clear the cache and try again

Note: running 'service supervisor restart' had no effect.

Comment: I switched to circus because supervisor couldn´t start more than a few hundred workers regardless how powerful my hardware was. No configuration change helped me. Here is the link.https://circus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Lumen and ran into the same issue. I tried `php artisan queue:restart`, which did nothing. I then found this thread and tried `php artisan clear-compiled`, as per the winning answer, but got the error:

*Command "clear-compiled" is not defined.*

I then saw that Artisan had the option `php artisan cache:clear`, which did the trick! When I fire that command followed by `php artisan queue:work`, my new job code is used.