# Laravel queue job doesn't updates to the latest code

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan, laravel-queue

I am using a laravel queue job to send emails with an excel attachment. And many a time it is happening, that whenever I update any code change, it doesn't consider the updated code, rather it runs the old code. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Restart the queue worker and it should be fine.

Comment: stop queue and again start after update code

Comment: Did that too, did a clear-compiled, restarted supervisor, cleared cache, views and all. But still it persists

Comment: run php artisan queue:restart

Comment: Tried that too Jacob

Comment: If you changed something in the settings or the .env file, you have to run `config:cache` as well. Depending on your server setup, you may have to actually kill the `queue:work` process instead of restart it.

Comment: @dimitri Is the config: cache essential. Usually, I go for clearing that. Also, the queue work is maintained by the Supervisor, which automatically starts or restarts the queue. Is it required to do so from my end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel 5.1 not seeing changes to Job file without VM restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881324/laravel-5-1-not-seeing-changes-to-job-file-without-vm-restart)

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the suggestion. My issue is resolved now. It was actually throwing up an exception, which was not being handled. I manually logged the exception and got the issue fixed. And now it is running fine. I guess if the supervisor is taking care of queue restart, manually queue: restart do help, I am not sure though, but it seems to be helpful.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Each time you deploy your Laravel app, or make any code change, you should run:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Of course make sure that in Supervisor you have set `autostart` to true.

You can read on https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#running-the-queue-worker :

> Since queue workers are long-lived processes, they will not pick up
> changes to your code without being restarted. So, the simplest way to
> deploy an application using queue workers is to restart the workers
> during your deployment process. You may gracefully restart all of the
> workers by issuing the queue:restart

Comment: This does not work if you use Laravel Envyoer and Forge. Tried many ways, and its impossible to restart without actually killing supervisor processors entirely. Wish there was another way.