# How did laravel call the onQueue method by wrapping new SendEmail($user) with parenthesis

Tags: php, laravel

I read this post [How to make function run in background in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451787/how-to-make-function-run-in-background-in-laravel), then I noticed this line.

```
$sendEmailJob = (new SendEmail($user))->onQueue('emails');
```

How did laravel call the `->onQueue` method by wrapping `new SendEmail($user)` with parenthesis?

I ask this question because I don't know what exact term to search for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a "fast way" to call a method inside a class, introduced in `PHP 5.4.0` , assuming that you only need that method and nothing else from that class, you can do something like

`(new myClass())->myMethod()`

this will prevent to use unnecessary memory for a variable that you will never use again. Is the same if you do something like

```
$class = new myClass();
$class->myMethod();
unset($class);
```

reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-178