# Laravel run script in background

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, background-process

in laravel is there a way to run code in the background?

For example:

```
public function video_merge()
{
    $video1="video1.mp4";
    $video2="video2.mp4";
    $cmd="command to merge video1 and video2";
    $id="xxxxxxxxxxxxx";//This "ID" I will use to check if the video has been merged
    //this code i want it to run in the background

    exec($cmd);
    updateStatusMerge($id,'ready'); //This function I will use to update the status is: video merging completed

    //end code running in the background

    return response()->json([
        'status'=>'processing',
        'id'=>$id 
    ]);
}
```

In the above code I want to merge two videos **video1.mp4** and **video2.mp4** with **ffmpeg** command how to make `exec($cmd); updateStatusMerge($id,'ready');` run in the background

Any documents or suggestions?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69917538/laravel-8-how-to-run-a-job-script-in-the-background

Comment: You can use [Artisan](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/artisan) and/or [Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues)