# How to keep a process running in the background? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, background-process, php-imap

I'm using the [php-imap](https://www.php-imap.com/) package and I want to listen for incoming emails.

The way to achieve this with `php-imap` is to call an `idle()` function, like this:

```php
$emailFolder->idle(function (Message $email){
   // dispatch event
});
```

The problem is that the `idle()` function never finishes running and the rest of the code is never executed.

I need to call the `idle()` function for each user, since I must listen for incoming emails for all of my users.

T've tried to set up a job for each user and dispatch it to a queue, but then the job never ends (and since the numbers of users changes, the number of workers must change), and I can't find a way to stop the job when needed.

I also need a way to stop the execution of the `idle()` function for a specific user, for example if the user deletes its account.

Is there a way to run that piece of code in the background, without it interfering with the code execution, with the possibility to stop the execution of a specific instance of the process?

Comment: Question: Have you considered about the "webhooks" or "polling" methods in combination with cron-job ? That's the way I would deal such case.

Comment: @aspirinemaga I cannot implement webhooks since every user connects with its own IMAP credentials and not all users might have the possibility to add a webhook to their mailbox (ex: Roundcube Webmail does not support webhooks). 

I want to avoid constant "polling" of the emails to avoid sending too many requests to the IMAP server, since a lot of them have request limits.

Comment: Does a job and queue suit your needs?, as answered in [https://stackoverflow.com/a/31452573/10579934](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31452573/10579934)

Comment: @javi Because the `idle()` function never stops running, the queued job never ends, and I'd have to create a worker for each instance of the `idle()` function (basically for each user, because each user has its own email credentials). Also, I need to be able to stop a job from running, for example if a user deletes its account, I must stop listening (through the `idle()` function) for incoming emails for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

Here it is: https://github.com/Webklex/php-imap/issues/206