# Laravel Supervisord cannot create file

Tags: laravel, supervisord

I am using Laravel Supervisor as job for exporting excel file.
Normal action was successful when using
`php artisan queue:work`
The file was successfully generated in 'public/excel' directory.

But when using supervisor, the job was executed, but the file was not generated.
I've checked folder permission, it's already 0777.
Here is the config file. I'm doing exactly like in documentation

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /home/xxxx/www/xxxx/artisan queue:work 
--sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
username=xxxx
password=xxxx
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/xxxx/www/xxxx/worker.log
```

Here's worker.log

```
[2017-12-08 20:44:42] Processing: App\Jobs\ExportExcel
[2017-12-08 20:44:44] Processed:  App\Jobs\ExportExcel
```

I have some command to write the database inside the ExportExcel job, and it's actually working fine. But the file is not generated. No error in laravel.log either

Comment: has the supervisor process been started successfully? Could you put the config as well? Anything in the logs btw?

Comment: It's started and I can use it, but it seems the file is not generated. When manually using php artisan queue:work, the file was generated

Comment: Whats the output of ls -la on the path to the folder that needs to be written to?

Comment: It's fine now, because i didn't clear the cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution(s) by:

-Laravel job '/' path doesn't refer to public therefore I move the exported data to storage path
https://laravel.io/forum/07-11-2014-file-permission-problems-in-queue-jobs

-Apparently server didn't use my updated code and still using old path. By using

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

The cache will be cleared and new code will be used. Thanks to one of the comment from this video
https://youtu.be/_SndYcQvIuQ

-By the time I posted this question, the file was actually generated but in other folder, but the controller was refering to the new path from the old code so it doesn't find the file.

Cheers

Comment: every time after deploying your code or doing a pull , you should clear cache and config

Answer (score 0):

In my case:
php: **7.4.2**
Laravel: **6.14**
maatwebsite/excel: **3.1.18**

All I had to do is to pass 3rd parameter for the store method.

```
Excel::store(new UsersExport(), 'users_2020.xlsx', 'local');
```

Here's the vendor file for it. It's the 3rd param **$diskName** where default is null. Even though my filesystem.php have `'default' => env('STORAGE_DRIVER', 'local')` set to local.

```
public function store($export, string $filePath, string $diskName = null, string $writerType = null, $diskOptions = [])
```