# php artisan queue:work freeze in terminal

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, laravel-artisan

I use the queue in  my **Laravel 5.4** project to send emails in background. 
I have created the table for jobs, created the class for the job, and put `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` in my .env file. When I dispatch my Job, I can see my task in the `jobs` table. So far so good.

However, when I then execute the command
`php artisan queue:work` on the webserver - it's freezing and not have any results.

What could be the problem?

[image: Queue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is because this is a service that uses the current thread in Ubuntu (from your tag). If you add a `&`, the process will run in a forked thread.

> php artisan queue:work &

Or after a [quick google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623001/how-to-keep-laravel-queue-system-running-on-server), you can have a look at

> nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &

Comment: Thanks, it's help)

Comment: You shouldn't run the queue worker like this though, you should really be using supervisor