# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 207:

Tags: laravel, command, command-line-interface

I want to run the `queue:listen --tries` command outside of artisan cli. For that i have written a  function "task" in `WelcomeController` and called it through routes. However it generates the above error. Codes are given below:

```
public function task()
{

    Artisan::call('queue:listen', ['--tries'=>'3']);
}
```

Routes as follows

```
Route::post('/fun', array('uses'=>'WelcomeController@task'));
```

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException is thrown whenever you don't match the method type when you access the route. So if you use `GET` request to a `POST` route you will get this error. So the `Artisan` call is never invoked.

Comment: but getting it change to get, couldnt run the code. and the 60s loading time error generates...so if you can guide

Comment: you are not returning anything from the controller method. Try at the bottom of the method `return 'Ok';` having `get` as a method type, and then use the browser

Comment: so . i changed it to     Route::get('/fun', 'WelcomeController@task');    ,but it throws Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: did you tried returning something from the method? That's what I wrote above

Comment: i did return ok  but same error of 60s timeout

Comment: public function task()
{

    Artisan::call('queue:listen', ['--tries'=>'3']);
    return 'ok';
}

Comment: The problem is because the `queue:listen` is a foreground job, so it listens to the queue without stopping, that's why it is hanging

Comment: There are some answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623001/how-to-keep-laravel-queue-system-running-on-server to run it in the background