# Push Notification not working after move my Laravel code from one server to another

Tags: laravel, firebase, laravel-5, push-notification

Please help me. After moved, my Laravel project from one server to another server, push notification is not working. I am using Firebase for push notifications.

I checked and got that handle function of Job is not working But When I run **php artisan queue:work** then I received a notification. I can not run manually each time. Please guide me on how to run dynamically. Any suggestion. Please guide me

Previously its worked fine but after the server change, I am getting this issue.

Comment: I updated my question. Please help me with this issue

Comment: I would suggest you contact the DevOps guy. Ask him to make some configurations to run `php artisan queue:work` automatically every time the server has restarted.

Answer (score 0):

Running this command could help.

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon &
```

Reference

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28625847/8197140