# Laravel - the page is busy when doing job

Tags: laravel, jobs

Im trying to send a job to the queue.

Controller

```
public function play($id, Request $request)
    {

        
        ProcessResult::dispatch($id);
        
        dd ('done');
```

Job

```
public function handle()
    {
        sleep(25) {
```

Code works is fine, but:

1. 'jobs' table is empty;
2. page in browser is busy until job is not completed;
3. dd('done') is not arrived until job is not completed;

Driver is database on localhost. Laravel 9.

What could be a mistake or a general misunderstanding of the logic of the queues?

Comment: It seems your jobs uses `sync` driver, check your env variable. Try to clear your config cache. `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: Yes, you're right! I changed to 'database' driver in queue.php ('default' => en('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),).

True, of course in .env.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your job is not queued. There are a few things that you must set up in order this to work the way you want. First of all, you must do the following in your job file

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class SomeName implements ShouldQueue {
     //....
}
```

After that you must install [supervisor](http://supervisord.org) and set up some things. You can find more information for how to keep laravel queue running in this thread

[How to keep Laravel Queue system running on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28623001/how-to-keep-laravel-queue-system-running-on-server)