# nohangup using ADB shell

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to do a logcat to a file using adb shell by following command -

`adb shell "nohup logcat -f /storage/sdcard0/myLog.txt -v time &"`

If I do a `ps | grep logcat`, I don't see the logcat command. Even I tried to see nohup command, but it is not there. So somehow above command does not work.

However if I perform the command in 2 steps it works fine -

1. adb shell
2. nohup logcat -f /storage/sdcard0/myLog.txt -v time &

I can see the process using `ps` and logcat continues to record to the file even if I disconnect adb shell. Now I would like the first command to work, since I am using python scripts to issue commands via ADB. It is possible to change the python scripts, however I would like to know if I am doing anything wrong in issuing the first command and if it is possible to make it work.

Comment: try using `busybox nohup` instead

Answer (score 0):

try

```
adb logcat
```

not

```
adb shell logcat
```

Comment: the reason to use adb shell logcat and not adb logcat is to be able to keep logging even if adb disconnects. I wanted to achieve that by using `nohup`.

Comment: I see. May be, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process) could help you then: