# kill nohup not working with kill -9 PID

Tags: linux, nohup

I have  server running with nohup on port 80. I try

```
ps aux | grep nohup
```

and get

```
root 9234 0.0 0.1 11740 932 pts/1 S+ 15:19 0:00 grep --color=auto nohup
```

I then try kill -9 11740 (which I believe is the PID) and get an error stating 'no such process." I can't figure out how else to remove this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This is interesting and may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process?rq=1

Comment: You try to kill the `grep` process that is already terminated (see the command on the right of the output).

Answer (score 1):

1. 11740 is virtual memory size. PID is the second field, 9234.
2. The process in your output is `grep` command itself, not nohup.
3. You won't see standalone nohup process. When you start some process with `nohup my_executable`, nohup closes/redirects stdin/stdout/stderr properly, setups necessary signal handlers and replaces itself with `my_executable`. Search instead for executable which was started with nohup, e.g. `ps aux | grep my_executable | grep -v grep`

Answer (score 0):

The process you are seeing is the process from your `grep` command. So by the time you are trying to kill it, the process is already over.

To keep it out of the output use:

```
ps aux | grep nohup | grep -v 'grep'
```

It looks like you don't have a `nohup` process running