# ubuntu nohup process log append instead of replace file

Tags: logging, append, ubuntu-16.04, nohup

I read this question 
[How to get the process ID to kill a nohup process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process) and the answer was great. However I need to ask if I write the "greater than" char twice in both cases like this

> nohup my_command >> my.log 2>>&1 &

instead of

> nohup my_command > my.log 2>&1 &

will it append to the same file instead of replacing it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Use `nohup my_command >> my.log 2>&1 &` to append the log files.

No need to change `2>&1 &`,
`2>&1` is ignore the stdin input.
Last `&` is to make your process background.