# Git pull successful, but IP address keeps showing the old version of the site

Tags: git, ubuntu, flask, virtual-machine, git-pull

I have a VM Ubuntu 16.04, running on Azure. 
I have a Flask app, running on it (perpetually, even after I log out of ssh).

I pushed to the repository, and pulled it on the VM side. However, when I go to the IP address, I see the old version of the site.
I've checked the templates in the VM, they are all updated with the new code, however, the site at the IP address is still the old version. I tried re-starting with flashing the cash (command+shift+R), but no result.

Why might this be happening?

Comment: You most likely missed something that's caching in between (CloudFlare, proxy)

Comment: @Info-Screen I am not in control of the Azure dashboard, just the VM. Is there anything that can be done on my end?

Comment: How are you running your Flask app? Unless it is in development mode, changes to your code will not take effect until you restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to restart the server. Since I ran it in the background using nohup, I had to kill the process. I used the link below to identify and kill the process:

[How to get the process ID to kill a nohup process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process)