# Run a java program even after putty terminal closed

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, jvm, putty

I use putty for taking linux machine terminal from my windows machine and run a java program.

Java Class

```
   try {

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                logger.info(new Date()+"...");
                i=i+1;
            }
        }, new Date(), 3000);

        if(i==50){
            t.cancel();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This program write a line in every 3 second. If I close the putty it stop running. Program become end, it not writing any more lines in the logger file.

How can I run java program in the backend or even in running state after closing putty terminal ?

Comment: How do you start your program from the command line?

Comment: I create a jar of my maven project and run a command java -jar test.jar

Comment: `nohup java <args>`, but, of course, logging or printing to the console has not much effect then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) command:

```
nohup java -jar test.jar &
```

Comment: Let me check this

Comment: what nohup exactly does ? and in my program I use logger. So, nohup is something related to this because it create a file nohup.out

Comment: From the attached link in my answer:
"nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.

Output that would normally go to the terminal goes to a file called nohup.out if it has not already been redirected."

If you are logging your output to console then it will be printed in nohup.out file instead. However if you are using your own log file, then nothing will change.

Comment: Hey there is some issue, according to my program, it will terminate when i==50 but when I run it using nohup it goes running and running.

Comment: In simplier words: nohup will not "attach" the java program you run to your ssh session. At the time of disconnecting all processes attached to your session are being terminated. The ones started with nohup command will not because they are not part of it.

Comment: How do you check if the program is still running ?

Comment: Sorry, thats my mistake in the program. One more thing I need to ask, if I run using nohup and after sometime I want to terminate the program. How can I do it ?

Comment: Please refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process)

Answer (score 1):

You can look into using the `screen` utility on linux which continues to run after after you logout of your session.

https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/ssh/using-gnu-screen-to-manage-persistent-terminal-sessions