# How to tag to a python command run in a bash shell

Tags: python, bash, ps

Is it possible to tag a python program run from the command line?

Context: Said command will be run with `nohup` in the background, and will be killed and restarted at midnight via `cron`. My intention is to pipe `ps` into `egrep` for said tag, grab the `pid`, and `kill -9` before restarting.

**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**

Start a python web server:

```
$ nohup python -m http.server 8888 &
```

Add a tag to the command. Note that `-tag` is just my imagination at work.. this is what I want:

```
$ nohup python -m http.server 8888 & -tag "ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003"
```

`grep` for tag:

```
$ ps aux | egrep "ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003"
```

...grab the pid from this, and `kill -9`

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process) can be helpful. in short, save the pid printed by `&` and then use it to kill the process

Comment: Maybe take a look at `man pkill`

Comment: maybe put all code in file with name `ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003` and run this file and then `ps aux` will show process `ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003` on list. And you could kill it using `pkill` with this name - `pkill ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003`

Answer (score 1):

Because you're saying that you want to kill the processes through isolated `cron` jobs at nidnight, I guess that the `$!` based solutions in the linked questions (like ([How to get the process ID to kill a nohup process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385794/how-to-get-the-process-id-to-kill-a-nohup-process?noredirect=1&lq=1))) are no option for you.

In order to identity your HTTP server processes, your idea is to 'tag' them with a unique ID so the cron jobs will find them.
What you *could* do in your specific case is to make use of the fact that the listening TCP sockets are unique on your given machine, and retrieve the associated pid through *netstat*.

A bash script along the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash
port=${1:-"8888"}
IP=${2:-"0.0.0.0"}

pid=`netstat -antp  2>/dev/null | grep -E "^(\S+\s+){3}$IP:$port\s+\S+\s+LISTEN" | sed -E 's/ˆ(\S+\s+){6}([0-9]+).*$/\2/'`

[[ -n "$pid" ]] && kill -TERM $pid
```

... that you parameterize with *IP and port* through your `cron`job.

Comment: why the `&` and `$!` based solution is not feasible with `cron`?

Answer (score 1):

You can put code in file with name `ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003`,

```
#!/bin/bash 

python -m http.server
```

set it executable

```
chmod +x ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003
```

run it

```
nohup ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003 &
```

and then you can kill it

```
pkill ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003
```

or even using only beginning of filename

```
pkill ced
```

---

**EDIT:**

Because new script doesn't get any arguments so you can run it with any argument(s) - ie. some tag/word

```
nohup ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003 hello_world &
```

and then you can kill it using `-f`

```
pkill -f hello_world
```

or even using part of word

```
pkill -f hello

pkill -f world
```

This way you can even use normal name for script and add `tag`

```
nohup my_script ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003 &
```

and kill with `-f`

```
pkill -f ced72ca0-cd19-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003
```

or using only part of word

```
pkill -f ced
```